# To not have QItemSelectionModel.selectionChanged called when using QSortFilterProxyModel

Tags: qt4, selectionmodel, qsortfilterproxymodel

I have a [QTreeview](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qtreeview.html) that uses [QSortFilterProxyModel](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qsortfilterproxymodel.html) to allow filtering by input text, and also uses [QItemSelectionModel](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qitemselection.html) to keep selections reflected on treeview.

Question is, is there any way to avoid the filtering result getting reflected on item selection?

Drawing what I want to achieve, what currently happens is this.

State-1. Initial.

```
Root
|---Leaf-1 Selected (manually)
|---Leaf-2
|---Leaf-3
```

State-2. After filtering by "Leaf-3" for example, treeview shows:

```
Root
|---Leaf-3
```

State-3-notIdeal. Then clear up filtering text then:

```
Root
|---Leaf-1 
|---Leaf-2
|---Leaf-3
```

I want "Leaf-1" to remain selected like:

State-3-ideal.

```
Root
|---Leaf-1 Selected
|---Leaf-2
|---Leaf-3
```

Looking into codes, when [QSortFilterProxyModel.filterAcceptsRow](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qsortfilterproxymodel.html#filterAcceptsRow) returns false, it looks like [QItemSelectionModel.selectionChanged](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qitemselectionmodel.html#selectionChanged)'s argument `deselected` is set with info of the items to be deselected. And I haven't found any way to distinguish whether an item was deselected by hand or by filtering.

I'm using `PyQt` on Ubuntu 12.10 but I assume this should be applicable to all `Qt` implementation.